# MPMoviePlayerController playback problem

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiosession

I'm having trouble with playing audio stream using `MPMoviePlayerController` in the background. On the foreground it's playing the audio just fine, but when the application goes to the background, sound disappears and the time keeps going. I have initialized the `AVAudioSession` with `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and have put the required background modes to audio in info.plist file. Also I have set `player.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;`. What could be the possible problem here? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

This [ios background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1668/_index.html) link indicates that the useApplicationAudioSession property value should be set to NO for iOS 3.2 and newer. (I have an app that does this and it works fine in background mode.